# Find all registration parcels in a given area

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, geoportal

I used map from geoportal website:

https://mapy.geoportal.gov.pl/imap/Imgp_2.html?identifyParcel=146505_8.0214

To the QGIS I import data source `https://integracja.gugik.gov.pl/cgi-bin/KrajowaIntegracjaEwidencjiGruntow`.

I want to generate list for all registration parcels in a given area.
For example in Warsaw I can identyfi area code `146505_8.0214` and next I want to generate list for all available registration parcels.
There will be:

- 3
- 6
- etc

Can I do it by Python script in QGIS? Or there is more smart way to collect this data?